# How i can solve ORACLE problem in foreign key

Tags: oracle

I have a problem in oracle and I need help. I have the following query:

```
1 CREATE TABLE TEST1 (
2 NAME VARCHAR(20) 
3 ID  VAR(9) 
4 PRIMARY KEY(ID) 
5 FOREIGN KEY(NAME) References TEST2(ANAME) 
6 ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE SET NULL );
```

If I want to delete line #6 what should i do?

Comment: ON UPDATE CASCADE is not valid in Oracle, So, just edit your statement to remove that clause.

Comment: If you want to delete line #6, then just delete it. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

"How I can change the value of primary key and based of that the foreign keys of this pk will change too?"

First, you should never need to do that. Primary keys like this are really just numbers that identify a row, they have no meaning in themselves. It's like asking how you would change the `ROWID` of a row.

If you must, you could:

1. Find the foreign keys pointing to this table and disable them with `ALTER CONSTRAINT myconstraint DISABLE`
2. Update your primary table and catch the new id value with `UPDATE test1 SET id = mysequence.NEXTVAL WHERE id = :oldid RETURNING id INTO :newid`, assuming it's set by a sequence.
3. Update the ids in your other tables with the new id.
4. Reenable your constraints.

Note that altering constraints is DDL and will do an implicit commit and this approach will leave your tables unprotected by the foreign key constraints.

A second approach would be to:

1. Insert a new row in the primary table and catch the new id.
2. Update the id in the foreign tables with the new id.
3. Delete the old row in the primary table.

Now that I think about it, that second approach seems better to me. No DDL and it just seems cleaner.